# Office 365 Distribution Group Sender Receives Copy of Group Email

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365

In Office 365, when someone sends a email to a distribution group they are a member of, they receive the message they sent in their inbox.  It does not skip their email on the list, and sends the duplicate message.  For example:

```
dave@contoso.com sends a message to group@contoso.com
dave@contoso.com receives the message that was sent to group@contoso.com*
Members of group@contoso.com also receive the message
```

*How do we prevent this step from happening?

Comment: Is dave@contoso.com ONLY a member of the group so that he can send to the group?  This is not truly a limitation.  ACL for sending to a group can be separate from the membership list, but the GUI "makes it easy" to say that only members can send to the group.  If this is a correct assumption, I'll expand as an answer.

Comment: No, dave@contoso.com also recieves from the group.

Answer (score 1):

All members of a Distribution group will receive messages addressed to the group. In hypothetical Dave's case, I would suggest an outlook rule to remove the item if it is a nuisance.

If the issue was a matter of controlling who can send to the Group, then it should be noted that there is a separate ACL for the ability to send mail to a group. `ReceivesMessagesFrom`

Comment: So is it safe to assume that they must set a custom rule for each inbox and not do it for the whole organization?

Comment: Yes. The user will need to set a rule that if he gets a message addressed to [distribution list], and sent from [himself], move message to recycle bin.  This would likely be an outlook-only rule, so he would probably get the messages on mobile if Outlook isn't online to process rules.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an O365 bug and should be reported as such. At minimum, they should have an option for "Yes, I want an Inbox copy of my own group email, even though it is in my Sent folder".

Answer (score 0):

In my organisation, we moved from on-premises Exchange to Office 365 during March 2017, and we noticed that emails sent to the group were no longer received by the sender in their inbox.  This was considered to be a problem since users were used to getting a copy of the email in their inbox.

This was the result of a feature update implemented by Microsoft in February 2017:
 (https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Office-365-Groups/Feature-update-Email-sending-behavior-for-Groups-in-Outlook/td-p/48673)

Therefore as a result of this change, the issue raised by David Eisen is no longer affecting users.  If users wish to confirm that their email was sent and received by the group, then they can check their Sent Items, and also they can open the relevant Group folder within Outlook.

Microsoft is considering (as of April 2017) implementing a further enhancement to address negative feedback, which I assume means providing a configuration option for senders to also receive a copy in their inbox once more!